# contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: magento2

I am creating one module. But in the controller getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Class HK\Faq\Controller\Faqs contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute) in \app\code\HK\Faq\Controller\Faqs.php on line 12
```

Here is the Faqs.php file I am not getting what is wrong in this file.

```
<?php

namespace HK\Faq\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
//use HK\Faq\Helper\Data;
use HK\Faq\Model\FaqFactory;

class Faqs extends Action
{
   /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
   protected $_pageFactory;


   protected $_dataHelper;

   protected $_faqFactory;

   /**
    * @param Context $context
    * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
    * @param Data $dataHelper
    * @param NewsFactory $faqsFactory
    */
   public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      PageFactory $pageFactory,
      //Data $dataHelper,
      FaqFactory $faqFactory
   ) {
      parent::__construct($context);
      $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
      //$this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
      $this->_faqFactory = $faqFactory;
   }

   /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
    {
       // Check this module is enabled in frontend
       $result = parent::dispatch($request);
        return $result; 

      /*if ($this->_dataHelper->isEnabledInFrontend()) {
         $result = parent::dispatch($request);
          return $result;
      } else {
         $this->_forward('noroute');
      }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **execute** method that is required.

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;
}
```